# VS dotnet core console application Cannot publish

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to publish a dotnet core self contained console application using Visual Studio 2017 community edition.

When I get to the step where I just need to click publish, everything seems fine for about 10-15 seconds then a window pops up with the following failure message.

```
Publish has encountered an error.
Publishing failed.

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
.....AppData\Local\Temp\tmp343.tmp
```

I then go to that file and this is the message...

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publishing failed.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<IsBuildCompletedSuccessfully>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.Model.DefaultPublishSteps.<DefaultCorePublishStep>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publishing failed.<---
```

Normally I wouldn't ask someone to take a look at the logs for me, but it's not telling me much. I was wondering if anyone else had a similar issue and they were able to resolve it.

Also, since someone might ask, I can successfully build and run the application. I've deployed it before. I recently made some changes to the app, but nothing significant. Just to be sure, I even switch branches to a known publishable app and tried to publish that version. Same issue. I'm thinking it has something to do with VS. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't have time to author an answer at the moment.  Is [this](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1039) discussion of any help?